# How can we found several words in C++ in a text file?

Tags: c++

In my project, I need to sort out a list in a file.txt file contains different words. I need my program to recognize this 3 names : bob, alicia and cookie. And each time when he found for exemple "cookie" I want to display "dog" as a result, for "alicia" "girl" and for "bob" "boy" and for an other word "unknown".

The text file contains :

```
hello
shirley
cookie
bob
alicia
cook
road
alicia
stole
bob
```

So I did this type of code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

  ifstream input;
  size_t pos;
  string line;

  input.open("file.txt");
  if(input.is_open())
    {
      while(getline(input,line))
    {
      pos = line.find("cookie");
      pos = line.find("bob");
      pos = line.find("alicia");
      if(pos!=string::npos) // string::npos is returned if string is not found
        {
          cout <<"dog \n";
          cout <<"girl \n";
          cout <<"boy \n";

          break;
        }
    }
    }
}
```

And when this code take file.txt like an entry I didn't have the right result like this :

```
unknown
unknown
dog
boy
girl
unknown
unknown
girl
unknown
boy
```

Can you help me please because I don't know can I have this result?

Comment: `pos = line.find("cookie");` then `pos = line.find("bob");` ... You keep replacing `pos` with a new value ignoring the last value.

Comment: What did you observe when stepping through our code line by line with the debugger?

Comment: @drescherjm so how can I resolve this problem?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I think, I didn't really understand you question sorry ?

Comment: He wants you to learn how to debug so that you understand what is going wrong yourself. I agree with him. This is an essential skill that every `c++` programmer needs to know.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ means there is a nifty tool you can use to control the execution of your code, stepping through it instruction by instruction if you have to. As you step, you have the debugger show you the state of all of the variables relevant to the error you are looking for. When you see a variable with the wrong value or you see the program do something different from what you expected, you probably found a bug and need to examine what lead up to the wrong decision more closely.

Comment: @drescherjm ok thank you I understand

Comment: @drescherjm no problem thank you

Comment: I deleted my last comment because that may fix the one issue but it would not do what you want to do. You need 3 separate comparisons to string::npos

Comment: Eventually you will learn better / more efficient ways to do this using the standard library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the stream extracion operator `>>` would have been easier:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    char const *filename{ "file.txt" };
    std::ifstream is{ filename };

    if (!is.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "Couldn't open \"" << filename << "\" for reading!\n\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    std::string word;
    while (is >> word) {
        if (word == "cookie")
            std::cout << "dog\n";
        else if (word == "bob")
            std::cout << "boy\n";
        else if (word == "alicia")
            std::cout << "girl\n";
        else
            std::cout << "unknown\n";
    }
}
```

---

If it would be required that only the first word of a line be considered a name one could write a manipulator that eats everything until a newline or `EOF` is encountered:

```
std::istream& eat_till_newline(std::istream& is)
{
    int ch;
    while ((ch = is.get()) != EOF && ch != '\n');
    return is;
}
```

usage:

```
while (is >> word >> eat_till_newline)
```

---

To further narrow down what a word is, one could remove all non-letters from the right of the string:

```
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

// ...

std::string r_trim(std::string str, int(*pred)(int))
{
    std::size_t i = str.length();

    if (!i)
        return str;

    for(; i > 0 && !pred(static_cast<int>(str[i-1])); --i);

    return str.substr(0, i);
}
```

usage:

```
while (is >> word >> eat_till_newline) {
    word = trim_r(word, std::isalpha);
    if (word == "cookie")
        std::cout << "dog\n";
    else if (word == "bob")
        std::cout << "boy\n";
    else if (word == "alicia")
        std::cout << "girl\n";
    else
        std::cout << "unknown\n";
}
```

---

To put it all together:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

std::istream& eat_till_newline(std::istream& is)
{
    int ch;
    while ((ch = is.get()) != EOF && ch != '\n');
    return is;
}

std::string r_trim(std::string str, int(*pred)(int))
{
    std::size_t i = str.length();

    if (!i)
        return str;

    for(; i > 0 && !std::isalpha(static_cast<int>(str[i-1])); --i);

    return str.substr(0, i);
}

int main()
{
    char const *filename{ "test.txt" };
    std::ifstream is{ filename };

    if (!is.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "Couldn't open \"" << filename << "\" for reading!\n\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    std::string word;
    while (is >> word >> eat_till_newline) {
        word = r_trim(word, std::isalpha);
        if (word == "cookie")
            std::cout << "dog\n";
        else if (word == "bob")
            std::cout << "boy\n";
        else if (word == "alicia")
            std::cout << "girl\n";
        else
            std::cout << "unknown\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: If line contains more than one word your approach won't work.

Comment: @kiranBiradar Do you see any extras in the sample file that shows which input to expect? And yes, it will work for extra words whereas the `getline()` approach with `find()` will not only find whole words like "bob" but also "bobby" which I'd consider wrong.

Comment: It seems it is OP`s concern now he mentioned in comments below.

Comment: @kiranBiradar Please mind that i updated my previous comment.

Comment: Your your approach is flawless if OP wanted to handle multiple words but it is just that he don't want to handle.

Comment: @kiranBiradar Did you ask him what should happen for `"bobby bob\n"` or `"bobby foo\n"`? Your approach prints `"boy"` for the first and `"boy"` for the second which i'd consider wrong since `"bobby" != "bob"`. My code prints `"unknown`" and `"boy"` for the first and `"unknown"`, `"unknown"` for the second. The question doesn't mention lines at all, and also no restriction to one word per line, but "each time when he found for exemple "cookie" I want to display "dog" as a result, for "alicia" "girl" and for "bob" "boy" and for an other word "unknown".".

Comment: We have provided answers for both requirements let him use whatever he wants :D

Comment: @kiranBiradar Sir, yes, Sir!

Comment: @kiranBiradar A `"bobby"` is still no `"bob"` though ;-p \*scnr\*

Comment: Haha!! Indeed `bobby` is `bobby` and `bob` is `bob`. Same personality different names :P

Comment: @kiranBiradar Impersonation?

Answer (score 1):

Few problems here

1. You are rewriting the `pos` in the while loop.
2. You only print `dog girl and boy` at once if you find `alicia` in the file(`pos` overwriting issue).
3. You are not handling the case for `unknown`.

Hence  replace your

```
while(getline(input,line))
{
  pos = line.find("cookie");
  pos = line.find("bob");
  pos = line.find("alicia");
  if(pos!=string::npos) // string::npos is returned if string is not found
    {
      cout <<"dog \n";
      cout <<"girl \n";
      cout <<"boy \n";

      break;
    }
}
```

with

```
while(getline(input,line))
{
    if ((line.find("bob")) != string::npos)
    {
        cout <<"boy \n";
    }
    else if ((line.find("alicia")) != string::npos)
    {
        cout <<"girl \n";
    }
    else if ((line.find("cookie")) != string::npos)
    {
        cout <<"dog\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout <<"unknown \n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
unknown
unknown
dog
boy
girl
unknown
unknown
girl
unknown
boy
```

> Note :: This approach finds the one word(including substring) in each line.

Comment: Think you very much I understand my different errors!

Comment: I tried now I just forget a case, for example if I have line with space how can I don't write "unknown" please? I tried now but my code doesn't work sorry

Comment: @cpeUser2018 If you use my answer it won't print `unkown` since `getline` will read complete line including space search for specific word(bob, alicia, cookie) in entire line.

Comment: yes I see that but how can I resolve this problem please ?

Comment: @cpeUser2018 Use my approach(`getline`).

Comment: I tried many things and particularly this ```else if ((line.find ("")) !=string::npos)
    cout << ""; ```  and the code doesn't take care about the unknown words if I code that

Comment: @kiranBiradar "This approach finds the one word in each line." Liar!! consider `"bobbiesA$$"` :p

Comment: @cpeUser2018 use `else if (line != " " && line != "")` to handle blank lines.

Comment: @Swordfish Now you are acting smart `"bobbiesA$$"` still has `bob` as substring.

Comment: your solution doesn't work correction because the program doesn't care again about the unknown words sorry @kiranBiradar

Comment: @kiranBiradar A word is usually delimited by whitespace and non-alpha characters like quotation marks, a comma or an exclamation or question mark and so on to its right.

Comment: @cpeUser2018 telling `your program doesn't work for unknown` isn't going to help. you should mention what input you are trying. With the given input in the question my program works perfectly.

Comment: @kiranBiradar sure, as long as there are no `"boby"`s nor `"aliciana"`s ;p ... and no `"cook` um, well, lets forget about the latter.

Comment: I wrote something like this .... `else if ((line.find("cookie")) != string::npos)
          cout <<"dog\n";
  else if (line != " " && line != "");` ... @kiranBiradar

Comment: @Swordfish dude what is your problem. The substring can be taken limitations or feature.and same I mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Use `else if ((line.find("cookie")) != string::npos) cout <<"dog\n"; else if (line != " " && line != "") cout<<"unknown"<<endl;` and  remove extra `else` block you have . @cpeUsr2018

Comment: @cpeUser2018 glad I was able to help you.